# Access to certain files but not others

Tags: ubuntu, file-sharing

Hoping someone can help me as I have, thus far, been unable to solve the issue.

I am running a media center utilizing Ubuntu 12.04.

I was initially successful accessing media files from the desktop running Ubuntu via my Windows 7 laptop and Roku device.

I started backing up a new batch of DVD's I had (into MKV files, like everything else in my media folders) and noticed I cannot access the new files from either the Roku or the laptop.

- I have not changed any settings in the media folder.
- I have verified the shared permissions.

  - The parent folder (Media) is shared (with permission flow-down) while the subfolders (Movies, TV Shows, Music) are not.
  - I have changed the permissions on this to include shared when the access problem arose but with no success.
- I can only access the original files uploaded an not new files added.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a few more specifics? How are you sharing the files? SMB? NFS? Something else? Also, can you be more specific about the permissions, error messages received, etc.? I don't think that there's enough key information in your post to be able to diagnose the problem.